# Probability about biased and unbiased coins

Tags: probability

a bag contains 20coins if the probability that the bag contains exactly 4biased coins is 1/3 and that of 5unbiased coins is 2/3 then the probability that all the biased coin are sortedout in exactly 10 draws is

Comment: 1. What exactly do you mean by *sorted out* ? 2. Can you show us the attempts you  have you made ?

Comment: Too many 'probability's and not enough periods, for this to be parsed as an English question.

Answer (score 0):

You divide cases:

1/3 : there are 4 biased coins 
2/3 : there are 5 biased coins

In each cases, the probability that you successfully sort out all biased coims in 10 draws is:

$\frac{16 \choose 6 }{ {20 \choose 10}}$ and
$\frac{15 \choose 5 }{ {20 \choose 10}}$ respectively.

Why? Well, the denominator should be obvious. The numerator, you can think of it as the number of 10 coins combination by fixing 4 ( or 5) biased coins (you can let it be the first 4 (or 5) since order doesn't matter), and only manipulating the rest(6 or 5) over 16 (or 15) remaining coins.

An example, for $16 \choose 6 $, would be like, {1,2,3,4,6,8,9,11,17,20}, {1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,18,19}, {1,2,3,4,5,7,13,14,15,17}, {1,2,3,4,15,16,17,18,19,20}, and so on. You'd see that number of these sets is $16 \choose 6$.

Finally you simply multiply each cases with the appropriate weights, and add them together:

$$\frac{1}{3}*\frac{16 \choose 6 }{ {20 \choose 10}}+ \frac{2}{3}*\frac{16 \choose 6 }{ {20 \choose 10}}$$

Comment: Except it says four _biased_ and five _unbiased._